# Change a list of items after its constructed

Tags: c#, list, f#

Please understand I just started programming F# Yesterday.

I have this algorithm in c# where I have a list of Nodes and those nodes have a list of children.

How can I achieve this? I know F# deals with immutable types and change a variable/object is not encouraged. What is a good way to go about it?

> C#

```
public class Node
{
    public List<Node> childrenNode = new List<Node>();
    public void AddChildren(Node node)
    {
        childrenNode.Add(node);
        node.Parent(this);
    }
}
```

> F#

```
type Node(board:Board)=
     let mutable _childrenNode= Set.empty
     new() = Node()
     member AddChildren(node:Node)=
```

Comment: Can you say a few more things about the algorithm? Existing answers show how you can reimplement the code line-by-line in F#, but that's not idiomatic - instead of creating node & adding children, you probably want to collect all children beforehand and then create a node once you have a complete list...

Comment: Your code makes the assumption that you create a node containing an empty list and the list contained within the node is added later.  This is sort of contrary to F# (and functional programming) idiom.  We don't create an object with a placeholder and fill it in later; we create the object with the content filled in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
type Node() as this =
    let children = new ResizeArray<Node>()
    let mutable parent : Node = this
    member this.Parent with get() = parent
    member this.AddChild(node : Node) =
       children.Add(node)
       node.Parent <- this
```

this is effectively the same thing as your C# code, although like you said, it does go pretty strongly against the F# mindset.

Comment: The last line in your snippet uses equality test, not assignment. Also, to get `new Node<Node>()` you need to open `System.Collections.Generic` - I'd use the F# alias `new ResizeList<Node>()` instead,

Comment: Where is `ResizeList<'T>` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I mean `ResizeArray<'T>`.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to represent tree structures in F# is to use discriminated unions. Here's an example that also adds the ability to store a value in each node:

```ml
type Tree<'T> =
    | Empty
    | Node of option<'T> * List<Tree<'T>>
```

So, the `Tree` type consists of two cases - either it's an empty tree or a node with an optional value and a list of children.

The data type is immutable so the add function requires you to pass an existing tree along with a list of additional nodes:

```ml
let addChildren (nodes: list<Tree<'T>>) (tree: Tree<'T>) : Tree<'T> =
    match tree with
    | Empty        -> Node (None, nodes)
    | Node (v,chs) -> Node (v, chs @ nodes)
```

Pattern matching is used to 
distinguish between the two shapes of `Tree` values.

Comment: Implicit in your answer is that generally in F# we define a data structure, and the functions which act on that structure, as opposed to C# (which the OP was attempting to transcribe), where the class contains its own functions.